# NullPointerException with non-null <key,value> pair in hashtable

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashtable

I get a null pointer exception with a hashtable 'get' method call. The key is definitely not null. I checked at 'check1'(commented in the code) by prining the value of the variable item. I have valid list of strings. I still get a null pointer exception. What am I doing wrong ?

```
       List<String> l= new ArrayList<String>();
            //Values added to l;
            Hashtable<String,int> h=new Hashtable<String,int>();

            for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++){
                String item= l.get(i);
                //check1
                int value= h.get(item); //exception arises at this point
                h.put(item,++value);
            }
```

Comment: I suspect that your actual code layout is not exactly the same as above. The `NullPointerException` has nowhere to come from except if `h` is `null` at that point.

Comment: `h.get(Object o)` can throw NPE according to the docs. does the `item`'s value null?

Comment: Could you please post the Stacktrace?

Comment: if `h` is `null` then only program will throws NPE. But here `h` is instantiated. So there is no way to get NPE.

Comment: @NagyVilmos: Yes, it can, but only if `o` is `null`, which seems impossible according to OP's statement.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code posted above doesn't even compile.

Comment: This was part of the code I submitted in HackerRank. I do not have access to the code anymore, but I am positive this how I implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile because `Hashtable<String,int>` is invalid. It should be `Hashtable<String,Integer>`.

The line `int value= h.get(item);` can throw exception for two reasons:

1. `h` is null (unlikely).
2. The value of `item` is not in the `Hashtable`, returning null, and the **auto-unboxing of `Integer` to `int` will throw `NullPointerException`**.

Comment: This was part of a challenge in HackerRank. I initially tried with <String,Integer> for which it threw an error. With limited debug info, the error went away when I auto-boxed Integer. However, I think, it is likely that I may have made a mistake in inserting key-value pair into the hash-table in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: How do I close this question ? I was looking for info on common errors people make to get NullPointerException. But now, the question seems to have no exact solution to my problem considering I do not have the exact code anymore. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the `Hashtable` as follows:

```
Hashtable<String,int> h = new Hashtable<String,int>();
```

This will not even compile. You'll get a Compiler Error.

You should change it as follows:

```
Hashtable<String,Integer> h = new Hashtable<String,Integer>();
```

Also, you can get `NullPointerException` in following cases:

1. If `h` itself is `null`.
2. If `item` is `null`.